# Can't Show custom error message for is_unique in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am using these form_validation rule to show an error message for a duplicate entry, but instead it shows default error message.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 
                                  'Email',                                      
                                  'required|is_unique[users.email]',
                                  'A User is already registered with this E-mail');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
        'email', 'Email',
        'required|is_unique[users.email]',
        array(
                'is_unique'     => 'A User is already registered with this E-mail : %s'
        )
);
```